# Gmail recipients are not getting emails sent using C#

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I had an working email sending functionality using c#. Suddenly gmail recipients are not getting the mails(neither in inbox nor spam). But other recipients (like outlook or any domain) are getting mails in their inbox.
Here is my code:

```
            SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage();
            System.Text.Encoding myEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            myMail.SubjectEncoding = myEncoding;
            myMail.BodyEncoding = myEncoding;
            myMail.From = (new MailAddress("Administrator@domain.com", "User Name"));
            myMail.To.Add("somemail@gmail.com");
            myMail.Subject = "Subject";
            myMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            SmtpMail.Port = 587;
            myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            myMail.Body = "<h1>Hi This is robin</h1>";
            SmtpMail.Host = "mail17.ezhostingserver.com";
            SmtpMail.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("useremail", "password");
            SmtpMail.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
            SmtpMail.Send(myMail);
```

However, I tried to manually send message from their Mail Application to a Gmail user. In that case the recipient is getting the mail. Mails only sent from the code to any gmail user is the main problem here.
NB: I have already tried `port:26`,  `SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = true`. Still no luck

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Gmail API Overview](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides):  _The Gmail API is a RESTful API that can be used to access Gmail mailboxes and send mail...Automated or programmatic message sending_

Comment: Did you read the warning in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient): "We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development..."?

Comment: The author appears to be connecting to their own domain ("Administrator@domain.com"), and not a gmail user account.  You can not use the gmail api with any other mail server then gmail.   Unless you think the author is using a google workspace domain account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, google was considering my emails as spammy and blocked the emails for reducing the amount of spam sent to Gmail.
Please visit https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError for more information